# Haskell Stack's executable profiling and ghc options fails to build

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to debug performance problems in a Haskell project, but I can't get profiling to be compiled in so I can use it through `+RTS -p` command line arguments.

The options for GHC in my `.cabal` file are:

```
ghc-options:         -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -Wall -Werror
```

Here's me attempting to build it:

```
stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-fprof-auto -rtsopts"
```

Which results in:

```
While constructing the BuildPlan the following exceptions were encountered:

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      base: needed (>=2 && <5), not present in build plan (latest applicable is 4.9.0.0)
      mtl: needed (>=2.1 && <2.3), couldn't resolve its dependencies
      random: needed (-any), couldn't resolve its dependencies
      transformers: needed (>=0.3 && <0.6), couldn't resolve its dependencies
      transformers-compat: needed (>=0.4 && <0.6), couldn't resolve its dependencies
    needed for package: MonadRandom-0.4.2.3

--  Failure when adding dependencies:    
      base: needed (>=4 && <5), not present in build plan (latest applicable is 4.9.0.0)
      stm: needed (>=2.0 && <2.5), couldn't resolve its dependencies
      transformers: needed (>=0.2 && <0.6), couldn't resolve its dependencies
    needed for package: StateVar-1.1.0.4
<snipped large log>
```

Even trying with just `stack build --executable-profiling` results in the same error.

For reference, my library dependencies are:

```
   build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
                     , aeson
                     , servant
                     , servant-server 
                     , wai
                     , warp
                     , either
                     , bytestring
                     , transformers
                     , postgresql-simple
                     , amazonka
                     , amazonka-sqs
                     , lens
                     , text
                     , time
                     , resource-pool
```

How can I resolve this so I can compile my project with stack and have profiling built in for use with `+RTS -p`?

Comment: In newer stack versions you can also just call `stack build --profile` as a shortcut for all the other flags.

Comment: See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/haskell/2970/stack/16600/profiling-with-stack) for more info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What does "stack exec -- which ghc" say?  If your ghc is installed globally, it could be that it lacks profiling libraries.  If so, "stack setup --no-system-ghc" + "stack build --no-system-ghc"

What is your stack.yaml configuration?  If you've set a resolver of "ghc-*", it won't work unless you specify the versions of all your dependencies in "extra-deps".  Usually you'll want to use a stackage snapshot - https://www.stackage.org/

Comment: `stack exec -- which ghc` says /usr/bin/ghc. My stack.yml just has `lts-5.17` for the resolver. I am trying `stack build --executable-profiling --library-profiling --ghc-options="-fprof-auto -rtsopts" --no-system-ghc` now. Should I remove ghc from the system?

Comment: I added `-threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -eventlog -prof` to `ghc-options` in my .cabal, and then ran `-threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N -eventlog -prof`. I can now get profiling information from my application and run with `+RTS -p`. Thank you for your help!